# JVM Terminates when Receiving POSIX Signal

Tags: jvm, signals, posix

I have a native C library that I load from Java using the JNA library.  That native C library has uses some POSIX signal hander under that hood that responds to SIGRTMIN +3 and possibly other SIGRTMIN + x.

When I run the java program from the terminal in Linux (64 bit Ubuntu), the program terminates and on the shell screen I see the text "Real-time Signal 3".  It seems that the library sends a signal SIGRTMIN +3 to its own process, however it looks like it terminates the JVM.

I can see how this could be the case as I believe the default disposition of an application that receives SIGRTMIN + x without an associated handler should terminate the application.  However, in this case, the library WANTS to handle the signal, but it seems that the JVM terminates upon its reception.

1) I have written a quick and dirty application that just sends SIGRTMIN + 3 (and other SIGRTMIN + x) to the process after launching the application from the shell and have confirmed that it DOES TERMINATE the java application.

2) I have read a lot of documentation on how java provides "signal-chaining" and have tried to launch the java application after setting libjsig.so using export LD_PRELOAD="...\libjsig.so " but have not been able to keep the application from terminating.

3) From what I have read, it does not seem like the JVM uses SIGRTMIN + 3 for its internal purposes, but there doesn't seem like much documentation in the way of how to suggest to the JVM to just chain a SIGRTMIN and not just terminate.

Is there a way that I can instruct the JVM not terminate and allow the native library to handle the signal?

Comment: Since you haven't told what JVM you are using, and haven't provided the test code, it's hard to say what is wrong. Meanwhile, HotSpot JVM does not do anything special regarding `SIGRTMIN+n` signals. That said, a native library can perfectly set up its own signal handler and prevent the process from terminating. Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/apangin/2b8716bbb4efe1239776a18ac04a4e9e).

Comment: have you actually registered a `sigaction` for the signal?

Comment: Sorry for not posting the code as i haven't made a striped down version of it.

Comment: SMH. So thanks for asking the obvious qustion of "Did you register sigaction".. Turns out the code uses sigtimedwait to wait for a signal.  When i went into the code and did something dirty and registered a dummy handler for SIGRTMIN+3, the code did execute the handler... So it seems the JVM only chains signal handers, and does not recognize the sigtimed wait.  Any suggestions?

Comment: As the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigtimedwait) says, in a multithreaded program, the signal should be blocked in all threads, in order to prevent the signal being treated according to its default disposition in a thread other than the one calling `sigwaitinfo()` or `sigtimedwait()`. Apparently, your library does not do that. Again, JVM does nothing special about these signals - it acts just like any other multithreaded process would do. It's up to you to install a signal handler or block the signal with `sigprocmask`.

Comment: Hmm... does the JVA execuate the C code in a thread other than the Java Main thread? If so I can see why it the process terminates as I never blocked the SIGMIN+3 in the java thread.  Otherwise, It looks like the JVM wants to have a signal disposition registered and if it does not get something to change the disposition from SIG_DFL, when the signal is received, the default SIGMIN+3 terminates the process.  The C library setsup only a sigwaitinfo() after blocking all signals... doesn't  'register' anything (that is change the SIG_DFL to some handler pointer)

Comment: 1. In a multithreaded program, a signal sent to the process can be received by *any* thread. 2. JVM is a multithreaded process. 3. You didn't block the signal in *all* threads. Therefore, a signal can be received by a thread other than the one calling `sigwaitinfo()` and thus cause the process termination. This sounds quite consistent to me, I don't understand what you find strange here.

Comment: Thanks for working with me on this.  So are u saying when I run the program from the command line... say java -Xrs jar program, then the JVM starts my program is multithreaded and my program can only block signals that start from my main... Thus any calls to native sigprocmask() blocking signals would not stop them fro, being sent to the JVM threads who started before my main.

Comment: Exactly. You'll need to block the signal somehow before the JVM starts multiple threads. E.g. in a LD_PRELOAD'ed library or in a custom JVM launcher.